# Unload source file with GDB

Tags: gdb, gdb-python

`(gdb) source script.py` loaded script file to GDB

How to unload that script? How to unload all loaded script or view all script that loaded ?

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

> How to unload that script? How to unload all loaded script or view all script that loaded ?

Think of `(gdb)` prompt as a shell. You can't "unload" a script anymore than you can "untype" a command you type into the shell:

```
$ FOO="bar"
$ source script.sh
```

Neither of above commands can be "unloaded".

If you need to reset the state of shell or `gdb`, start a new instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

The script is "sourced", not "loaded". The script executed and exited. Hence you can't unload it. It may have left something after itself (pretty-printers, commands, breakpoints, changes in configuration etc). You can't unload them all as a group, you have to find them and undo one-by-one.